# Need help with a regular expression for ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion-9

I would love some help with a regular expression that tests a string for a few things.

I need the user to enter a value that is at least 10 characters in length, contains at least 1 number, at least 1 special character, and at least 1 upper case letter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a separate regex for each of the constraints:

- at least 10 characters in length: `.{10,}`,
- contains at least 1 number: `[0-9]`,
- at least 1 special character: `[^0-9a-zA-Z]`
- at least 1 upper case letter: `[A-Z]`

And make sure that the string matches all of these regexes.

If you really need it, you can combine them all in one regex, using lookahead assertions:
`(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^0-9a-zA-Z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,}`

Answer (score 0):

The length requirement is probably easier to test without a regex.
The other tests would work better as separate tests as well:

number: `[0-9]+`

upper case: `[A-Z]+`

special (punctuation characters):    `[[:punct:]]+`

trying to combine them into one regex would probably yield something rather unwieldy, and unclear